Is there a way to access HBase with Thrift and Kerberos in Rust?
I successfully implemented a Rust sample app that accesses an HBase server without authentication using the hbase-thrift crate. Now, I need to access HBase with Kerberos authentication. Since the HBase Thrift does not have a SASL Transport layer implementation, I implemented the code to acquire a service ticket separately using the libgssapi crate.
I am facing difficulties integrating this with the hbase-thrift code. Are there any Rust-based solutions or references that I can look into for implementing access to HBase Thrift with Kerberos?
If Apache Thrift support libraries lack a SASL Transport implementation for Rust ( https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/lib/rs/src/transport ) , unlike Java and Python, should I give up on accessing Thrift with Kerberos in Rust?
